# Customize Alfresco form, when workflow completed

Tags: javascript, forms, workflow, alfresco-share

We are doing some customizations for the Alfresco workflow details page
by manipulating Share-config.xml

when workflow is in progress, all the fields in the workflow details are displayed as expected.

But when workflow **completes**, We are not able to view the workflow details page customization and it is rendering as default form.

**is there anyway we can customize it, after the workflow completes.**

Any Dom manipulation ways also fine.

Sample code, what we are trying

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="icmrWf:submitArtefactTask">
        <forms>

            <form id="workflow-details">
                <field-visibility>
                    <show id="bpm:groupAssignee" />
                    <show id="icmrWf:workgroup" />
                    <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
                    <show id="packageItems" />
                </field-visibility>
                <appearance>
                    <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.workflow.more_info" />
                    <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />

                    <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
                </appearance>
            </form>

        </forms>
</config>
```

[image]